# Adding spouse to Wyoming LLC as managing member

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, wyoming

I own a WY LLC as a sole member. I want to add my spouse as a second managing member, and I understand I must amend the LLC's operating agreement in order to do it.

As this is the first time I'm amending an LLC's operating agreement, would anyone be able to point me to a straightforward template I could use?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is it just you and your wife? I don't know anything about WY law, but I did a quick skim and know something about LLC laws in other states. You might be OK with just a verbal agreement with just your spouse... If you need also to amend your Articles of Organization, it looks like WY state provides that at http://soswy.state.wy.us/Forms/Business/LLC/LLC-Amendment.pdf

Comment: @Brick this is articles of organization, that's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @littleadv Yes - I stated the same and provided the Articles of Org as additional information. The first part of my comment addresses the operating agreement - which it's not clear requires any form or document at all in the situation described by the OP.

Comment: You cross-posted this to Law.SE: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/adding-spouse-to-wyoming-llc-as-managing-member.  Please don't do that.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: That's right, I'm talking about the operating agreement, not the articles of organization. I checked with WY, an amendment on the OP does not required amendment of the articles.

Answer (score 1):

Operating Agreement is a legal document, and as such an attorney should draft it. There are a lot of "boilerplate" templates available on various sites that provide LLC-organization services or access to legal forms - but these are boilerplate forms. They don't cover specific situations that you may need to cover.

Generally, while for single-member LLC boilerplate may be enough in many cases, when the LLC becomes partnership - I'd suggest talking to a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks. I just really wanted a simple one-pager for now, as it's a startup and we would not wish to spend money on this for now. Later on we intend to make it tighter with the help of a lawyer, especially if we are to take new members. I need an document for the OP amendment as I would add my spouse as signatory on the bank account as well.

Comment: Then just write one. Find the section in the current OA that says "Single-member LLC" and change it to "Multi-member LLC".